Is closing my DockerClient also closing the InputStream I got from it?
I'm getting an InputStream from my dockerjava client, but closing my client seems to close the stream too. Why is this?
Can't send exact code but it's basically doing something like this
...
private void FailingMethod(String containerId){
    ...
    DockerClient client = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).withDockerHttpClient(httpClient).build();
    InputStream stream =  client.copyArchiveFromContainerCmd(containerId, ".").exec();
    client.close();
    int lineCount = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream)).lines().count()    
}

config is of type DefaultDockerClientConfig and httpClient is of type DockerHttpClient, they were set earlier but I excluded the code for them since it's convoluted and probably irrelevant. When debugging the method fails when I try to read the stream with BufferedReader on the last line with a java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException. When comment out client.close(), the BufferedReader line runs successfully.  How is my DockerClient related to my InputStream s.t. closing it closes the stream too?

How do you think the InputStream returned from client.copyArchiveFromContainerCmd(containerId, ".").exec() works, internally? I've never worked with docker-java, but I would assume it works by calling the client. Which doesn't work, after you've closed it.
